# copy data from one textbox to another when document is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a form, when the document is ready, I am trying to copy the preset value of a textbox to another textbox using jQuery. I tried     `$("#b").val() = $("#a").val();` but, it dint work. Please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z693R/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b").val($("#a").val());
});
```

Comment: +1 `.val()` retrieves the value, and `.val(newvalue)` sets it. Trying to assign to the retrieval won't work

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
$(function() {
    $("#b").val($("#a").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do:

```
$(function() {
    $("#b")[0].value = $("#a")[0].value;
}
```